# React App Clickhandler Validation Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, components

I'm trying to fetch data from json server and validate it with the value entered into input fields.
If the fetched data and input data are the same it needs to add a div between fields and description text.
I've already created that component too and i think its ok.

I have already set the onChangeHandler but OnClickHandler i didin't accomplish the validation between inputs and related json fields.
Maybe i need to use a loop for validation ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ApplyButton from '../ApplyButton/ApplyButton';
import axios from 'axios';
import IsApplied from '../IsApplied/IsApplied';

const NumberContainer = styled.div`
    margin-top: 10px;
`;


export default class NumberBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            giftcards: [],
            first: '',
            second: '',
            isSeen: false
        };
        this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
        this.onHandleChange = this.onHandleChange.bind(this);
    }

    onHandleChange (property) {
         return e => {

         this.setState({
            [property]: e.target.value 
        });
      };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/giftcards')
        const giftcards = response.data
        this.setState({giftcards: giftcards})   
    }

    onClickHandler() {

        if (this.state.first === this.state.giftcards.cardnumber && 
            this.state.second === this.state.giftcards.control) {
            return alert("correct") & this.setState({isSeen:true})
        } else if (this.state.first.length === 0 &&
             this.state.second.length === 0) {
            return alert("error")
        } else {
            return alert("enter correct number") & console.log(this.state.giftcards)
        }
    }

    render() {
        let resultsbox;            
        if (this.state.isSeen) {
            resultsbox = <IsApplied cardno={this.state.first}/>;
        } else {
            resultsbox = null;
        }

        return (
            <NumberContainer>
              {resultsbox}  
                <TextField
                style={{ margin: 8, width: 430 }}
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
                type="search"
                label="Gift Card Number"
                value={this.state.first}
                name="cardNomber"
                onChange={this.onHandleChange('first')}

                />
                <TextField
                style={{ margin: 8, width: 200}}
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
                type="search"
                label="Control Code"
                value={this.state.second}
                name="controlCoder"
                onChange={this.onHandleChange('second')}
                />

                <ApplyButton handle={this.onClickHandler}/>
            </NumberContainer>
        )
    }
}
```

```
{
    "giftcards": [
        {
            "cardnumber": "5078282848878291861",
            "control": "175"
        },
        {
            "cardnumber": "6435047555924007105",
            "control": "201"
        }

    ]
}
```

I'm getting undefined for this.state.giftcards.cardnumber & this.state.giftcards.control while checking with console.log

Comment: How can i iterate through array values? Because with index numbers it will be hardcoded.

Comment: That will depend on how you want your feature to work. When the onClickHandler executes, do you want to find a card that matches exactly with the user inputs? Like some sort of filter?

Comment: Yes, i want to match the input value and JsonData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.setState({giftcards: giftcards}).`

You're setting `giftcards` state-value equal to an object. That JSON object has a key of giftcards. So at the minimum your condition in `onClickHandler` has to be something like :

```
if(this.state.first === this.state.giftcards.giftcards[index]){
....
}
```

Since the key giftcards, has an array for its value, you also have to decide which item in the array you want it to check against like this.state.giftcards.giftcards[0].cardnumber...

However, it sounds more like you just want to filter some data to determine whether the user entered the exact same information of a card.

We can use `array.filter()` to return any giftcards that match your user inputs. If any, then we will set isSeen to be true. Try doing something like this for `onClickHandler()`:

```
onClickHandler(){
    const { giftcards, first, second } = this.state

    const matchingGiftCards = giftcards.filter((card) => {
        return card.cardnumber == first && card.control == second
    })

    //if there are any matching giftcards we will set isSeen to tru
    if(matchingGiftCards.length > 0){
        this.setState({isSeen:true})
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christopher.
matchingGiftCards in if statement is coming out is not defined.

Comment: Oh there was a typo :)

Comment: @Nefraim yeah sorry about that haha. Glad you caught that, did it work for you?

Comment: I have changed the onClickHandler as you said but didin't worked. I got nothing, not a clue about working or not man. :)

```javascript

 onClickHandler() {
        const { giftcards, first, second } = this.state
        const matchingGiftCards = giftcards.filter((card) => {
            return card.number === first && card.control === second
        })

        
        if (matchingGiftCards.length > 0){
            this.setState({isSeen:true}) 
        }
    }

```

Comment: Man i figured it out. Just changed ```card.number``` to ```card.cardnumber``` and its now working.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Nefraim lmao, okay yeah that's on me, I definitely was rushing to create that example for you. Thought I was writing the write syntax. :)